# error 1366 incorrect string value when inserting korean character into the database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that has a collation of euckr_korean_ci but whenever i insert an entry in the database with korean characters i am having an error 1366 incorrect string value.

I tried running the files directly in HeidiSQL and i encountered an error:

[image: error]

I also tried importing the sql file in phpmyadmin but the file is too big.

I tried on mysql workbench i still encounter the same error i got from importing it with HeidiSQL.

Comment: what is the datatype of userName column..

Comment: varchar(20) NOT NULL default ''

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use `Nvarchar` and also alter your table and set the character set to `UTF8` and `collate to utf8_unicode_ci`

Alter Query :-

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Hope it works.

Comment: thanks for this, i haven't tried it yet for the whole .sql file have 600,000 lines and i am not sure how to do that. and also, i do not know the names of the tables. the error comes when importing the database so i am not sure how to alter it if its not yet imported.

Comment: do one thing just took the backup of your database as a backup and apply alter query on the backup copy..

Comment: just check the name of the table from insert query in which you are inserting data..

Comment: i can some of the tables but not all because the database is so big. i am currently tryin your solution on a single table, i will be back for updates.

Comment: you are creating a database from the coding or the database has been already created and  you are putting(inserting) data into it..please tell me.

Comment: are you going to insert that data in one table or in multiple tables?

Comment: yes it will try to take backup and alter your tables in which you are inserting data..